# Oddity with UTF8 in perl regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I'm working on some Perl code that handles possibly malformed UTF8, and have come across an oddity with regex matching.  Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $string = "One \x{FFFF_FFFF} three\n";

my $re1 = qr/\x{FFFF_FFFF}/;
my $re2 = qr/.*\x{FFFF_FFFF}/;
my $re3 = qr/.\x{FFFF_FFFF}/;

print "One\n" if $string =~ $re1;
print "Two\n" if $string =~ $re2;
print "Three\n" if $string =~ $re3;
```

The output is:

> One
>   Three

Why doesn't the second regular expression also match? Is there a work-around?

I'm using Perl 5.14.2.

Comment: it does for me with Perl 5.18

Comment: I get the behavior you expect from v5.20.1

Answer (score 2):

Because of a bug that's already been fixed in 5.18

```
$ usr/perlbrew/perls/5.16.3t/bin/perl -wE'
   say "One \x{FFFF_FFFF} three\n" =~ /.*\x{FFFF_FFFF}/ ?1:0'
0

$ usr/perlbrew/perls/5.18.2t/bin/perl -wE'
   say "One \x{FFFF_FFFF} three\n" =~ /.*\x{FFFF_FFFF}/ ?1:0'
1
```